# Autenticarse en PHP con busqueda en array

Tags: php, html, array

Buenas, queria saber como podria hacer que este codigo, al loguearse, compare si las credenciales son correctas comparando los valores de un array. Lo hice con un foreach, comparandolas con if, pero el resultado que me da es que todos pueden entrar.

```
<?php   
    $usuarios = array (
        "juan@juan" => "juan",
        "pedro@pedro.es" => "pedro",
        "maria@maria.es" => "maria"
    );
    if($_POST)
    {
        if (isset($_POST["email"])) 
            $email = $_POST["email"];
        else $usuario = "";
        if (isset($_POST["contrasena"]))
            $contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];
        else $contrasena = "";

        if($email != "" && $contrasena != "")
        {
            foreach ($usuarios as $emails => $contrasenas)
            {
            if ($email = $emails && $contrasena = $contrasenas)
            {
                $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
                header ("Location: contenido.php");
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                header ("Location: registro.php");
                echo "Introduce email y contraseña correctos";
            }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header ("Location: registro.php");
            echo "Introduce email y contraseña correctos";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

El principal error es porque dentro del `If` lo que está haciendo es una asignación con `=`  y no una comparación , para que realice la comparación debería ser `==`

```
if ($email = $emails && $contrasena = $contrasenas)
//Cambiar por 
if ($email == $emails && $contrasena == $contrasenas)
```

Como recomendación sería bueno que para este caso pueda manejar una variable `boolean` para saber si el `login` fue exitoso o no para luego mostrar los mensajes o redireccionar como desee, porque tal cuál está mostrará el mensaje 3 veces en el caso que sea erróneos los datos.

```
$usuarios = array (
        "juan@juan" => "juan",
        "pedro@pedro.es" => "pedro",
        "maria@maria.es" => "maria"
    );
if($_POST)
{
    if (isset($_POST["email"])) 
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    else $usuario = "";
    if (isset($_POST["contrasena"]))
        $contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];
    else $contrasena = "";

    $estado = false; // Variable adicional
    if($email != "" && $contrasena != ""){
        foreach ($usuarios as $emails => $contrasenas){
            if ($email == $emails && $contrasena == $contrasenas)   $estado = true;
        }
    }

    if($estado){
        $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
        echo "Ingreso Correcto";
    }
    else{
         echo "Introduce email y contraseña correctos";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `array_intersect_assoc()` para simplificar un poco las cosas, el `foreach()` es innecesario y con dos `if` es suficiente, también es recomendable finalizar el script cuando se cumple alguna de las condiciones y no necesitamos que se ejecute el resto.

Ejemplo simple comentado:

```
<?php
    // Nuestro array de usuarios
    $usuarios = array (
        "juan@juan" => "juan",
        "pedro@pedro.es" => "pedro",
        "maria@maria.es" => "maria"
    );
    // Validamos si se han enviado los datos
    if ( isset($_POST["email"]) AND isset($_POST["contrasena"]) ) {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];
    } else {
        // Si no hay datos redirigimos y finalizamos el script
        header ("Location: registro.php");
        echo "El email y contraseña no fueron enviados";
        exit;
    }

    // Validamos si existe el email y contraseña en nuestro array
    if ( array_intersect_assoc(array($email => $contrasena), $usuarios) ) {
        // Si existe asignamos, redirigimos a contenido.php y finalizamos el script
        $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
        header ("Location: contenido.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        // Si no Coinciden datos redirigimos y finalizamos el script
        header ("Location: registro.php");
        echo "Introduce email y contraseña correctos";
        exit;
    }
```